# Wireshark isn't decrypting 802.11 traffic

Tags: encryption, wireshark, wifi, wpa

I have read and followed Wireshark's [guide](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11), and successfully decrypted the example file, but when it comes to my file it doesn't work. I have made sure that both the SSID and the password are correctly spelled in the settings. The entire EAPOL handshake is present, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is a screenshot of the handshake:

[image]

Maybe the problem is that there more than 4 packets?

Here is the [pcap file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_FVGdqvgb2PUFd5c3dRU0dpTGM), in case it helps. The password for the AP is "privacyblibwifi".

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This file decrypted fine in my version of wireshark (2.2.4) when I added the following line to my 802.11 decryption keys:

wpa-pwd: privacyblibwifi:npodeploy